# Get subset of column from before the first non blank

Tags: python, pandas

I need to get a subset of a pandas Series starting from the cell before the first non-blank one.

Ex: For the series:

```
>>> s = pd.Series([np.NaN, np.NaN, 1], index=['a', 'b', 'c'])
>>> s

a    NaN
b    NaN
c    1.0
dtype: float64
```

I need to get the subset containing rows 'b' and 'c'. Like this:

```
b    NaN
c    1.0
dtype: float64
```

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

s = pd.Series([np.NaN, np.NaN, 1], index=['a', 'b', 'c'])
lst = s.index.to_list()
s[lst[lst.index(s.first_valid_index())-1:]]
```

Is there a simpler and/or faster way to do this? **Note that the data may contain blanks in place of NAs.**

Comment: Enough clarifications please. If you have an issue with the existing answers, please modify your data and expected output to show what you want and why what you currently have does not work.

Comment: @cs95 Thanks for your answer. However, when implementing it, I found anomalies in the data. These issues can't always be predicted in advance.

Comment: It would be more appropriate to open a follow up question as people have already taken time to answer and your edits will invalidate their solutions :)

Answer (score 4):

Use `get_loc` (and you won't have to depend on `let` anymore either) and `first_valid_index`, this is slightly more readable:

```
s[s.index.get_loc(s.first_valid_index())-1:]

b    NaN
c    1.0
dtype: float64
```

This will work assuming your index values are unique.

---

To handle blanks, use `replace`,

```
s2 = pd.Series(['', np.NaN, 1], index=['a', 'b', 'c'])
s2[s2.index.get_loc(s2.replace('', np.nan).first_valid_index())-1:]

b    NaN
c      1
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

I will using `idxmax` and `bfill`

```
s[s.loc[:s.idxmax()].bfill(limit=1).notna()]
b    NaN
c    1.0
dtype: float64
```